# Swapping a UIImageView's image while rotating and moving leaves traces of original image

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, animation, uiimageview

I am taking the "Flipped Text" imageView and rotating it while moving it downwards on the screen and adjusting the frame. I am also swapping out the image for a different, but similar image.

Everything works as indicated except for the image crossfade is still showing the original position  for the fade-out instead of following the movement. This screenshot shows the original, transition and end states for the animation, and clearly shows the problem.

[image]

My code looks like this (`logoImage` is a `UIImageView`):

```
// Swap it
self.logoImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = duration;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
[self.logoImage.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];


// Spin it
CABasicAnimation* spinAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
spinAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:6*M_PI];
spinAnimation.duration = duration;
spinAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
spinAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
spinAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[self.logoImage.layer addAnimation:spinAnimation forKey:@"spinAnimation"];


// Shrink it and Move it
CGRect newFrame = [self logoFrameForInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.logoImage.frame = newFrame;
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

**How can I make the crossfade of the image swap happen in place?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping the image in the *completion block*. (currently nil)

*edit:*
If they are substantially different, you can use a second UIImageView.  Fade one out while you fade one in.  You can either do this while they are translating, or wait for the "shrunken" original to arrive and fade it out while the "better" smaller version fades in.

Then remove the unneeded extra view in the completion block of that animation.

Comment: The images are too different to do it this way (mirror images of each other). It does solve the problem of the lingering original image, but it causes an abrupt jump between the 2 different images at the end.

Comment: use a second `UIImageView`, place it and fade between the two, then remove the other when it is faded out

Comment: And then make sure the 2 image views get the same frame animations. I was hoping for something a little more elegant, but I think this could work

Comment: Just implemented your comment and it works. Edit your answer and if there is a not-so-heavy answer added, I will accept yours

Comment: @coneybeare could you update your question adding the resulting solution code?  It would help me a lot.